# Error: You must pass a function as a selector to useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

It showing error on useSelector ...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xl9s.png)

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useNavigate();
  const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
  const userPhoto = useSelector(selectUserPhoto);
```

[userName and userPhoto code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAkHI.png)

Comment: could you show a code of these two methods ```selectUserName``` and ```selectUserPhoto```

Comment: Yes i have added image now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSelector` expects you to pass a callback function as a argument and in the callback function you are supposed to return whatever value you want from redux store, so for example your redux store consists of bunch of elements shown below

```
 {
      user: {
        firstname: "first name",
        lastname: "lastname"
      }
      imgUrl: "https://some-url"
    }
```

so now lets say if you want to access user field from the entire store you can do `userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.user);` this will return you the user object from the redux store

so since you were not passing the function as an argument to the `useSelector hook`, hence the error `you must pass function as selector to useSelector` so you are basically using the function as a selector to select what part of the redux store you want to access

Comment: after this it showing error...: src\components\Header.js
  Line 25:43:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 26:44:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: can you please add the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

useSelector is a Higher order function, as an argument you have to pass a function to it, like below:

```
const username = useSelector( (state)=>{state.user} )
```

Comment: after this i get error  : src\components\Header.js
  Line 25:43:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 26:44:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.